# Creating an Athena view on a HUDI table returns soft deleted records when the view is read using SPARK

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-athena, apache-hudi

I have multiple HUDI tables with differing column names and I built a view on top of it to standardize the column names. When this view is read from Athena, it returns a correct response. But, when the same view is read using SPARK using spark.read.parquet("<>") , it returns the soft deleted records too.
I understand a HUDI table needs to be read with spark.read.format("hudi") but since this is a view on it , I have to use spark.read.parquet("").
Is there a way to enforce HUDI to retain only the latest commit in the table and suppress all the old commits?

Answer (score 0):

Athena view is a virtual table store in the metastore Glue, the best way to have the same result of Athena in Spark is by using AWS Glue as metastore/catalog for your spark session. To do that you can use [this lib](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-data-catalog-client-for-apache-hive-metastore) which allows you to use AWS Glue as an Hive metastore, then you can read the view using `spark.read.table("<database name>.<view name>")` or via an SQL query:

```scala
val df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM <database name>.<view name>")
```

Try to avoid `spark.read.parquet("")` because it doesn't use the hudi metadata at all, if you have issues with Glue, you can use Hive to create the same view you created in Athena for spark.